# Why does my UINavigationController crash on release configuration?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a requirement to remove a previous view controller in a stack.  I have successfully used this method in the past, without any problems:

```
NSMutableArray *vcs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    BOOL removedFlag = YES;
    while (removedFlag == YES)
    {
        removedFlag = NO;
        for (UIViewController *vc in vcs)
        {
            if( ![vc isKindOfClass:[self class]] && ![vc isKindOfClass:[MenuVC class]] )
            {
                [vcs removeObject:vc];
                removedFlag = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithArray:vcs]];
```

Now I’m updating the app, and it mysteriously crashes on release configuration, not on debug.  In addition, there are no warnings whatsoever in debug mode.  I think something changed with the SDK.  It never did this before.

I’ve made a sample project available:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7834263/RemoveTest.zip

This is an ARC-enabled project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line should actually be:

```
NSMutableArray *vcs = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
```

NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray. `arrayWithArray` is a method of the NSArray class -- it creates an immutable array. The `mutableCopy` method creates a mutable copy of the original array. You never really should have been able to call `removeObject` on your vcs array because it was never actually an NSMutableArray -- it was an NSArray.

Comment: This works, but why?  Don't both arrays hold references to the objects?

Comment: =Strange I've never had a problem with this before.  When I check the contents of the vcs array after removal (in my code above), it only shows the two view controllers, so it is removing them.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to remove the previous viewController in the stack could be:

```
 int vcIdx=[self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]-1;
 NSMutableArray *vControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers]; 
 [vControllers removeObjectAtIndex:vcIdx]; 
 self.navigationController.viewControllers=vControllers;
```

Comment: I'm actually removing multiple controllers in my project, but I didn't specify that.  Yes, this is nicer.

Comment: Oh, i thought your requirement was to remove the previous controller :)